# Is WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName null-terminated?

Tags: winapi

The documentation for [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740.aspx) says of the `cFileName` member the following:

> ```
> TCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH];
> ```
>
> ....
>
> **cFileName**
>
> The name of the file.

Is it safe to assume that a `WIN32_FIND_DATA` returned by `FindFirstFile` or `FindNextFile` is null-terminated? I'm nervous that there might be a convention that if there was no null-terminator, then the string would be MAX_PATH long.

Comment: How would you determine the string length, if it wasn't? I didn't find authoritative information, but would be surprised, if all strings in the Windows API are C-style strings, except for this one.

Comment: Assuming it has been properly filled out (I.e., the `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` succeeded), yes. Otherwise, how would you figure out what the length is?

Comment: @IInspectable That's what I feel. But I wonder if there might be some strange pattern that if there was no null-terminator, then the string would be `MAX_PATH` long. It would be a nightmare to work with I agree.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the answer, but I could imagine a scheme where, if the name was less than MAX_PATH it would be zero-terminated, and if it's not zero-terminated then the length is exactly MAX_PATH.  Ya know, like how CP/M and other early file systems did it, which led to the funky behavior nobody expects from strncpy.

Comment: @Adrian That's the scheme I am imagining.

Comment: MAX_PATH = 260  is longer than the longest permissible filename = 255, and in any case for paths, MAX_PATH includes the terminating null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355865/is-win32-find-data-cfilename-null-terminated#comment52585286_32355865) above is good enough for me:

> Assuming it has been properly filled out (i.e., the `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` succeeded), yes. Otherwise, how would you figure out what the length is?